# Realtime Database permission denied (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to know if the player is already in a game or not but I'm completely new to the database programming. I keep getting this error

2022-02-07 17:32:51.787097+0100 Troeven2.0[64029:2674017] 7.10.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at / (and here the correct! user id of the current user) failed: permission_denied

update** and the error handler returning:

Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Denied}

**

I find this rather weird as the user has full rights how I see it to write and read his own data, rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my data structure is as follows:

[image: data structure link]

and my code that I use to acces is this:

```
func checkIfInGame(completionHandler: @escaping (_ completionHandler: Bool) -> Void) {
    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child(currentUserID!).child("gameInfo")
    
    ref.observe(.value , with: { (snapshot) in
        if let directory = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let gameID = directory["gameID"] as! String
            let isInGame = directory["inGame"] as! String
            var flag = false
            if isInGame == "yes" {
                flag = true
            }
            completionHandler(flag)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print("error checking in game")
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

it's also maybe handy to know that my code immediately prints the error "error checking in game"
any help and time is really appreciated!

Comment: Not directly related to your permissions issue, but you'll hit this next: `ref.observe` is an *asynchronous* function. You won't be able to immediately return a `Bool` from `checkIfInGame` like you're trying to do. Look into "callback functions" or "completion handlers"

Comment: that could explain why a print statement that is after the function got printed first, thanks for that insight already!

Comment: Did you `print(error)` yet? That will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Also note that the `".write": "$uid == auth.uid"` you have under `$uid` doesn't do anything, as it's overridden by the `".read": "auth.uid != null"` that you have un `/users`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Comment: I just added the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake that wasted my day: I did not go into child("users") hence no permission was granted. I also switched to getData since I only needed the data once when asked....

```
func checkIfInGame(completionHandler: @escaping (_ completionHandler: Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let currentUserID = currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserID)
    
    ref.child("gameInfo/inGame").getData(completion:  { error, snapshot in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return;
        }
        let test = snapshot.value as? String ?? "no";
        
        print(test)
    })
}
```